# Assertion Error while using stanford-sentiment-treebank-roberta.2021-03-11.tar.gz in ALLENNLP

Tags: allennlp

I have created a virtual ubuntu machine and installed ALLENNLP,
In that and tried example from [ALLENNLP demo website](https://demo.allennlp.org/sentiment-analysis/roberta-sentiment-analysis)

I have executed below code

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
import allennlp_models.tagging

predictor = Predictor.from_path("myLocalPath/stanford-sentiment-treebank-roberta.2021-03-11.tar.gz")
predictor.predict("a very well-made, funny and entertaining picture.")
```

which gave me below error.

```
>>> predictor.predict("a very well-made, funny and entertaining picture.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/text_classifier.py", line 24, in predict
    return self.predict_json({"sentence": sentence})
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/predictor.py", line 54, in predict_json
    instance = self._json_to_instance(inputs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/text_classifier.py", line 40, in _json_to_instance
    return self._dataset_reader.text_to_instance(sentence)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp_models/classification/dataset_readers/stanford_sentiment_tree_bank.py", line 114, in text_to_instance
    assert isinstance(
AssertionError
```

But when I executed below code

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
import allennlp_models.tagging

predictor = Predictor.from_path("myLocalPath/sst-roberta-large-2020.06.08.tar.gz")
predictor.predict("a very well-made, funny and entertaining picture.")
```

It worked.

Only difference between above two code is version of **roberta-large** train data

I have installed latest version of ALLENNLP in my virtual machine
I don't have NVIDIA graphic card in my virtual machine could this be a reason?
But then how come other version is working?

Please help

Comment: I just tried it myself and it worked just fine. Can you post more context of what you're doing?

Comment: Thank you for your replay @DirkGroeneveld , I have tried to explain situation more clearly by editing my question , please let me know if need any more information.

Comment: Is it possible you trained stanford-sentiment-treebank-roberta.2021-03-11.tar.gz with an older version of AllenNLP?

Comment: Actually I have reinstalled everything, I even recreated a new virtual machine and downloaded stanford-sentiment-treebank-roberta.2021-03-11.tar.gz again to make sure that any old installation is not impacting, could you please let me know which versions of ALLENNLP and pytorch you installed so I can install those and try again?

Comment: I tried your exact code on the latest AllenNLP, and it worked. I only changed the URL to point to https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/stanford-sentiment-treebank-roberta.2021-03-11.tar.gz, because I don't have access to your local model. So it must either be a problem with your model, or with something you installed into your environment. How did you install AllenNLP?

Comment: Thank you so much @DirkGroeneveld for helping me out, you are right, ALLENNLP version was the issue, I had installed version 2.1.0 with command "pip install allennlp==2.1.0 allennlp-models==2.1.0" as mentioned is website modal usage section, I got confused and thought this will be the latest version but when I installed it using "pip install allennlp" without specifying version (Installed latest available version) it worked.

Comment: @DirkGroeneveld If you are somehow connected with ALLENNLP could you please let them know to change websites demo section example with version 2.4.0 instead of 2.1.0, It will avoid confusion for others.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I made a PR to update the demo here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/pull/259

Answer (score 0):

Allen NLP version was the issue it was ALLENNLP 2.1.0, It worked with ALLENNLP version 2.4.0.

Use command "pip install allennlp"
and then "pip install allennlp-models"

instead of "pip install allennlp==[some version] allennlp-models==[some version]"

or make sure you have version greater than or equal to 2.4.0.